# How to show albums that have at least one approved photo

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables: one is `album` and the other one is `album_photo`. I need to show albums which have at least one approved photo. I have following fields for tables:

```
album
Id    name        date
1   myalbums      1-1-10
2   youralbum     2-3-10
3   somealbum     3-4-10 

album_photo
id album_id   photo_url   status
1    2        /some/url   Pending  
2    1        /some/url   Approved
3    1        /some/url   Approved
3    3        /some/url   Declined
```

In the above table only album with id 1 ("myalbum") has approved photos, the other two albums do not have any approved photos. So I want a query which displays the names of albums which have at least one approved photo.

I tried like this:

```
select a.*, a.id as album_id, ap.*  
from album a,  album_photo ap
where a.id = ap.album_id
and (select count(*) from album_photo where ap.status = 'Approved') > 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You query is slightly wrong in spite of joining them at begaining just join them inside where clause.

```
select a.*,a.id as album_id from album a
where (select distinct ap.album_id  from album_photo ap where 
ap.album_id=a.id and ap.status='Approved')>0;
```

Rest all you did is correct.
Another solution is without distinct as we know ids are always unique so distinct in inner query can be removed and can be written as below.

```
select a.*,a.id as album_id from album a
where  (select count(*)  from album_photo ap where 
ap.album_id=a.id and ap.status='Approved')>0;
```

Comment: This is very inefficient because of the unnecessary `count(*)`. You are better off with a `DISTINCT` clause like in the other two answers.

Comment: @Patrick id in album_photo is always unique and distinct only, so whenever there are photos will have different ids only, in above case I think its not necessary to take distinct.

Comment: There are 10 ways to skin a cat. That does not make them equally efficient. Use of `count(*)` is bad advice in this situation where you are testing for presence and not for a specific number.

Comment: Mr. Sudarshan, your "improved" query is wrong. Think before you write.

Comment: @Patrick what should i do tell me sir. when I have written query with count see many people accepted it. but still i changed according to u, what should I write tell me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77301/discussion-between-sudarshan-and-patrick).

Answer (score 1):

the following query should return al the albums (ant all its photos approved or not) that have at least one photo approved.

```
select a.*,a.id as album_id,ap.*  
from (select a1.* from album a1 where a1.id in (select distinct ap1.album_id    from album_photo ap1 where ap1.status='Approved')) a,  album_photo ap
where a.id=ap.album_id;
```

if you want only the albums without the photos you can use

```
select a1.* from album a1 where a1.id in (select distinct ap1.album_id     from album_photo ap1 where ap1.status='Approved')
```

Comment: same got repeated rows of albums_photos

Comment: did you try the second query?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM album a
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM album_photo ap
    WHERE ap.album_id = a.id AND ap.status = 'Approved'
);
```

EXISTS produces a semi-join which can be expected to perform better than a join.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.id AS album_id, a.name, a.date, ap.id AS photo_id, ap.photo_url, ap.status
FROM album a
JOIN album_photo ap ON ap.album_id = a.id
WHERE ap.album_id IN 
  (SELECT DISTINCT album_id
   FROM album_photo
   WHERE status = 'Approved');
```

The sub-query finds the id for all albums that have at least 1 photo approved. The main query then shows all photo details from all those albums.

Comment: Well, then why did you include `ap.*` in your query?

Comment: The `distinct` in the sub-query is unnecessary.

Comment: See Mr. @Patrick  I was correct, check above comment.You made me to change my solution

Comment: But wouldn't use of `distinct` make the query run faster because it returns fewer rows?